# How to use Rar or WinRAR for creating an encrypted archive with a password starting with a double quote?

Tags: command-line, special-characters, rar, winrar

I am trying to create a command line to compress as RAR file using password through command line in Windows 7. I have installed WinRAR 5.31 x64.

The following command works for me:

```
rar a -r -m0 -hp"!(/!$!#!#=)\%" C:\files1.rar" *.*
```

The password is `!(/!$!#!#=)\%`.

My problem occurs if I wanted to put double quotes `"` inside my password, for example at the beginning:

```
rar a -r -m0 -hp""!(/!$!#!#=)\%" C:\files1.rar" *.*
```

The password should be `"!(/!$!#!#=)\%`.

That does not work for me, I tried putting `\` before of `"`, but this is also not working.

Could anyone guide me through it in order to figure it out this special character in my password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` and `Rar.exe` itself determine how arguments specified on command line are interpreted on parsing the command line. Argument strings containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|> `` must be enclosed in double quotes. This makes it very difficult to pass a double quote character as part of an argument string to a console application, especially at begin of an argument string.

But there is a solution for this very uncommon and very specific problem caused by a password/passphrase starting with a straight double quote character which marks usually begin/end of an argument string within all characters between are interpreted literally.

The manual of console version of WinRAR is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of **WinRAR**. It can be read in this manual that `Rar.exe` supports reading switches from an environment variable `RAR`. By using this environment variable and special parsing of Windows command line interpreter on a **SET** command line it is possible to create a RAR archive from command line with a password starting with a single straight double quote character.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "RAR=-hp""!(/!$!#!#=)\%%""
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -r -m0 -x"%~f0" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\files1.rar" *.*
endlocal
```

The switch `-hp` is read from environment variable `RAR` in addition to the other switches specified directly on RAR command line as explained by the manual.

The environment variable `RAR` is defined using syntax `set "variable=value"` as explained in detail by answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

A password/passphrase with space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|> `` needs to be enclosed in double quotes on Windows command line. For that reason `Rar.exe` removes from the passed password/passphrase the first and last double quote if there is one at begin and/or end. So it is not possible to define the password with `"!(/!$!#!#=)\%`. The password must be defined with two additional double quotes using `""!(/!$!#!#=)\%"` to let really used password start with a straight double quote character.

In a batch file `%` marks begin/end of an environment variable reference except it is escaped with one more `%`.

So finally the command line `set "RAR=-hp""!(/!$!#!#=)\%%""` defines the environment variable `RAR` with switch `-hp` passing the string `"!(/!$!#!#=)\%` to `Rar.exe` as password to use on encryption.

The RAR archive `files1.rar` is created on user's desktop by this code as root of directory `C:` is usually write-protected.

**Note: Rar** and **WinRAR** interpret `*.*` different to `*` as also explained in manual in comparison to Windows kernel functions interpreting them identical. **Rar** adds only files containing a dot in name of file into the RAR archive file on using `*.*`. So you might better use just `*` as wildcard.

The switch `-x"%~f0"` prevents adding the batch file also into the RAR archive file if being stored in current directory on execution of the batch file. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for an explanation of `%~f0` – full name of argument 0 which means batch file name with extension and full path.

Answer (score 4):

Further to the answer by Mofi:

Especially for Linux users using winrar/rar from the commandline, it may be worth realizing that `rar` effectively accepts "keyfiles", which may overcome the need to fiddle with quotes as part of the password.

Rar's documented maximum password length is 127 characters/bytes. It is not clear (to me) precisely which characters are part of the password space, but at least base64-encoded strings work. However, [`rar`](https://www.win-rar.com/enc_faq.html?&L=0#c7720) currently uses a password based key derivation function based on PBKDF2 using the HMAC-SHA256 hash function, which has a block size of 512 bits. Per [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#HMAC_Collisions), passwords longer than the block size of the hash function are first pre-hashed into a digest of 256 bits, which digest is then used as the password (instead of the original password). To [avoid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/what-are-requirements-for-hmac-secret-key) this, the archive password you pick should be no longer than 512 bits or 64 characters.

In a base64-encoded string, each character represents 6 bits of data; a 64 character password thus amounts to 384 random bits, which may be derived from 48 random bytes.

```
rar a -hp"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=48 count=1 | base64 -w0 | tee /tmp/pwd)" archive
```

The `dd`-pipe above will read 48 (pseudo)random bytes from the kernel's (non-blocking) random number source device, convert these into a 64 character password, tell `rar` to use that password for deriving a 256-bit (AES256) encryption key (RAR5-format), and at the same time store the password in the file `/tmp/pwd'.

The archive may again be accessed, e.g. listed, by reading the password back from the file, for instance like so:

```
rar l -p"$(cat /tmp/pwd)" archive.rar
```

The password file may be safely stored separately or together with the archive, in the latter case (of course) after encrypting it, e.g. with `gpg` using your own public key so as to lock the archive password under your private key/key phrase. All of this aims to conveniently make good use of `rar`'s password/key space.

I note that I didn't dive into `unrar`'s publicly available source code; the above is merely based on the general documentation. In addition, I don't know if the above can be made to work under Windows.